# How can I mock the created field of a model that inherits from TimeStampedModel using model_mommy?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, model-mommy

I am trying to test a date filter but have been unable to set the created date using mommy.make(). When I make the objects with model mommy the created field is set to the time the objects were created rather than what I passed in with mommy.make()

```
def test_mommy(self):
    today = arrow.now()
    yesterday = today.replace(days=-1)

    mommy.make('Model', created=today.naive)
    mommy.make('Model', created=yesterday.naive)

    model_1_created = Model.objects.all()[0].created
    model_2_created = Model.objects.all()[1].created

    self.assertNotEqual(model_1_created.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), model_2_created.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

This test fails with the Assertion Error:

```
AssertionError: '2018-03-15' == '2018-03-15'
```

I may have a misunderstanding of how model_mommy creates these objects. But I would think this should create it and set the created dates properly. Though it looks like the default TimeStampedObject behavior is taking over.

Comment: You do not know how many `Model.objects.all()` in a TestClass with many test methods. assign and assert `foo.created` and `bar.creaed` should do it without the need to save it.

Comment: This was the only test in the TestClass so I think I could be confident about the state of Model.objects.all()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to save the created by dates after the objects had been created. I think this could have also been achieved by overriding the save method on TimeStampedModel. But this seemed like the simpler solution.

```
def test_mommy(self):
    today = arrow.now()
    yesterday = today.replace(days=-1)

    foo = mommy.make('Model')
    bar = mommy.make('Model')

    foo.created = today.naive
    foo.save()
    bar.created = yesterday.naive
    bar.save()

    model_1_created = Model.objects.all()[0].created
    model_2_created = Model.objects.all()[1].created

    self.assertNotEqual(model_1_created.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), model_2_created.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```